# winforms output to commandline

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms application. I would like to run the .exe from the commandline and redirect the output from one of the output textboxes to the commandline. I don't want to launch the winform application just run the logic in the background.

I tried the advice from this thread

[C# application both GUI and commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198639/c-sharp-application-both-gui-and-commandline)

but I didn't see any of my console.writeline messages in the command line in cmd.exe when I ran the application via the cmd.exe. Can anyone guide me as to what I might be doing wrong?

I have an if statement that did this logic:

```
  if(args.Length >0)
   {
     Console.writeline("this has arguments");
     new Mainform();
   }
  else
   {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
   }
```

The else part still works. But nothing happens in the if part either using the cmd.exe to run the application or when I use the properties ->debug->command line arguments and give it arguments to run while debugging it. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Move logic into separate dll and use that dll both from forms and from console application

Comment: so make two different applications? One for Winforms and one for Console?

Comment: Exactly. And both applications will use same business logic, which will be independent from UI you are using

Comment: It isn't visible because a Winforms app doesn't have a console.  Pinvoke AllocConsole (not AttachConsole, output gets intermingled).  Your form isn't visible because you forgot Application.Run().

Comment: That's what I did finally and it worked. Another question though: In order to get the prompt back i need to put System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you created your `Windows Forms project` and pasted the code? If so, it couldn't work. You have to create your `Console project` and here is the code I've tested, works like a charm except that when the Form is shown (GUI mode) the Console is still there, closing that Console will also close your Form:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            else //Process command lines
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter some command.");
                string cmd = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You entered: " + cmd);
            }            
    }
}
```

Because the `Console project` doesn't add reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` automatically for you, so you have to do that manually to be able to create your form in that Console project. The point is that you applied the code in a `Winforms project` while it should be in a `Console project`. There is only a way I know which can show a Console window in a winforms application is running the `cmd.exe` but that will show a new Console window than the existing one which you are using to run your application.

Comment: Thanks. yeah I figured that out eventually by myself. I do attach to process now instead and it works. I am trying to find a non hackish way of getting back the prompt without having to hit enter. I used System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); but my boss is unhappy with that solution and sees it as hacking it.