# How to open a text file in C#/WinForms/TextBox - mad Editor

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have developed a Text Editor in WinForms. you can download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/textpadv1/) and use it. It works fine. But when I right-click a text file in Windows Explorer and try to open it, it doesn't show it. 
I have searched solution for this on Web, but failed. Can you suggest a resolution to this. 
Or should I use RichTextBox. 
I also tried to create a simple Test project with `RichTextBox` and used `LoadFile()`.

```
// Load the contents of the file into the RichTextBox.
richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

This caused a file format error.

Comment: Try looking here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c-sharp

Comment: File Association doesn't work. I want to know how to access a file selected in Windows explorer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem. Thanks for your help.
I am adding answer for future help who face the similar problem.
Here is the solution:

Call the following method from Form_Load():

```
public void LoadFileFromExplorer()
{
   string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

   if (args.Length > 1)
   {
     string filename1 = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];
     richTextBox1.LoadFile(filename1, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
   }
}
```

To make this work, change Main():

```
static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            // run as windows app
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using:

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

you have to choose a [*Rich Text Format (RTF)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) file, so this is because loading a normal text file gives you a file format error (ArgumentException). So you could load it in this way:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(openFile1.FileName);
richTextBox1.Lines = lines;
```

Comment: Actually my problem is when I right click a text file and click open with this program, then this program should open the text file. In reality an empty text editor is displayed. I have seen on web the solution may be "var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();" but still no success. Trying my best.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so based on your comments and the code provided it won't open the file from windows.

When windows sends a file to a program to open it, it sends it as the first paramater to the exe, e.g. `notepad.exe C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\FileToOpen.txt`.

You'll need to grab the arguments using `Environment.CommandLine` or `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`.

See here for further info: [How do I pass command-line arguments to a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application)

I would handle this in your form's `Load` event and pass the argument to your function:

```
string filename = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
richTextBox1.LoadFile(filename, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

Comment: Also for future reference, if you post an answer saying "This is how I did it" you won't be able to mark it as an answer, essentially leaving the question unanswered. =]