# how to pass file as parameter to your program wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

i create a very simple photo viewer using c# wpf i just need to open the image directly into my app
like default windows photo viewer.

so i need to pass the image file as parameter to my app

i found [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554362/opening-image-directly-into-program) but it for winforms not wpf.

i hope that you could help me.

sorry for bad English.

Comment: Google **File Association c#**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle file open - triggered for example when double-clicking a file in Windows explorer - simply run the following C# code when the application has been started (e.g. in the main window's "Loaded" event):

```
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if (args.Length > 1)
{
    var fileName = args[1];
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        if (extension == ".MyDocumentExtension")
        {
             // TODO: Open file from fileName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have made an small edit . now it works . Thanks alot

Comment: @AhmedTarek, this answer is about how to pass file as parameter to your program, which for me is different to your question: *to open the image directly into my app like default windows photo viewer.*. You may want to update your question.

Comment: Yes, the question for me means "How to register a file association in Windows" but is actually "How to load file from application arguments"

Comment: So, you changed it back to the original?