# C# Open winform from commandline

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, command-line

I am new to c# and this project is for the purpose of learning only. I trying to make a program where the user enters some information inn a command line, and then the result is displayed in a forms window. How can I make that work?

Here is my failed attempt:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Øving1
{
    class Program
    {
       static int Length;
       static int Width;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GUI test = new GUI();

            Console.WriteLine("Dette Programet regner ut areal og omkrets av et rektangel, angi en lengde og brede(eks. 10 enter 10)");
            Length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("AREAL: " + Area(Length, Width) + " OMKRETS: " + Circumference(Length, Width));


            test.richTextBox1.Clear();
            test.richTextBox1.AppendText("AREAL: " + Area(Length, Width) + " OMKRETS: " + Circumference(Length, Width));

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(test);


        }

        public static int Area(int Length, int Width)
        {
            return Length * Width;
        }

        public static int Circumference(int Length, int Width)
        {
            return (Length * 2) + (Width * 2);
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Here is the error: https://app.box.com/s/wutvm68n69cl6d87eqma

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't really understand that error message but `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` must be called before the window is created (e.g. before form constructor is called).

Answer (score 1):

You generally can't mix console and winforms applications together. It's technically possible, but the framework is generally designed to treat these as separate application types: [Show Console in Windows Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472282/show-console-in-windows-application)

If your goal is to allow data input from commandline prior to displaying the form, consider just using command line parameters, which are much easier to support in a winforms application: [How do I pass command-line arguments to a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application)

Comment: That does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @SLaks. What I said is correct. There is no console in a winforms application by default, and you can't exactly create display a form in a console application very easily. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can easily create a form in a console application.  A console application is just an EXE that also opens a console.

Comment: Well, okay, it's possible to go the other way (winforms from console application), but that leads to other problems. See Tergiver's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277771/how-to-run-a-winform-from-console-application. I think that the conceptual problem is best solved with commandline parameters, depending on the amount of data.

Comment: It is quite possible to go either way. No one promised that you won't have to write any code, though. The easiest way is to create a WinForms application, and then use `AllocConsole` and `FreeConsole` to create and destroy the console window, respectively, as desired. And I don't know what you mean about command line parameters. Those don't really have anything at all to do with the console window.