# C# Add my Application to Send To When i RightClick on a file

Tags: c#, windows

I want to add my Application so when I right click on a file , it shows the Send To > My App.

If its possible then , when I click on the SendTo button , how can I get the Selected file ...?? 
I didn't tried anything before or even found something that can help.
Thanks :=)

Comment: You are really being vague here. You want to add your application to what? Click on a file where? You really need to give some context.

Comment: I think he means right-clicking on a file in the Windows Explorer window or Total Commander, and adding his program as an option to the 'Send To' item.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a shortcut to your application to

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

To navigate to that folder, you can also open a explorer window and type

```
shell:sendto
```

into the addressbar.

When you use the `Send To` context menu, a new instance of your application will be started and you can get the path to the file which you sent to your application via the commandline arguments. For a console application this would be the `args` parameter of the `Main` method. Another way is `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`.

---

**Edit: Add sample console application**

```
namespace TestApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String filePath = args[0];
            Console.Write("The file you sent here: ");
            Console.WriteLine(filePath);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that the app ist started with no other arguments. If there are other arguments, the filepath could be on another index in the `args` array.

Sample output of this console app could be:

```
The file you sent here: C:\tmp\file.txt
```

Comment: i didn't understand how can i get the File i selected ? can You Show me an example Please?

Comment: I edited the answer and added a sample console application source.

Comment: thank you , but the problem is that when i add shortcut to my app on the SendTo Folder , it doesnt show on the list when i rightclick ?

Comment: Did you add the shortcut for the correct user. The SendTo directory is user specific.

Comment: I tried it on a Windows 7 machine, what version are you working on?

Comment: I had another try on Windows 10 and realized I mentioned the "Roaming" folder separately in my answer but it's already included in the %AppData% environment variable. I edited my answer accordingly. Maybe this is the reason it's not working? To be sure you should try it with `shell:sendto`.

Comment: Cool , now its working thank you.
can i know how to get the filename in a C# GUI ? not console.. :) thank you.

Comment: You can use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(). Be careful, the GetCommandLineArgs also returns an String array, but the first item is the executable file name. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application