# Application.Exit Isn't closing my program, any alternatives?

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-arguments, exit, kill-process

So in my form constructor I have a check for an argument. If I get one of two special arguments then I want to just register/unregister my server and close the program. I don't want the form to load in these instances. However as it currently stands the following code successfully registers/unregisters the server, but it doesn't kill my application right after like I want it to. Any other command to do so? Or maybe there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

My code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        instance = this;
        fillMeasView();

        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Length > 1)
        {
            switch (args[1])
            {
                case "register":
                    try
                    {
                        slikServer1.RegisterServer();
                        MessageBox.Show("Server registered successfully!");
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not register server." + "\nAdditional Information: " + ex.Message, "Registering Server Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    Application.Exit();
                    break;
                case "unregister":
                    try
                    {
                        slikServer1.UnregisterServer();
                        MessageBox.Show("Server unregistered successfully!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not unregister server." + "\nAdditional Information: " + ex.Message, "Unregistering Server Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    Application.Exit();
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("This is the cmd line arg:" + args[1]);
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Move that code to `Main` method (application entry point) and don't show form at all instead of exiting anything.

Comment: @Sinatr you're saying to create a main? That'll add ambiguity in terms of the programs start point won't it?

Comment: You already have it... somewhere ;) Do not create new, use/modify existing one. There is even special version of it: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1179545/1997232).

Comment: @J.Doe Put the checks in the program start point (`main`). Then only load the form if needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: what does that command do exactly? I'll give it a try now thanks

Comment: @J.Doe it kills the process and assign ExitCode = 0

Comment: "Terminates this process and returns an exit code to the operating system." - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Nope still not working for me, form1 still seems to load. EDIT: forgot to apply it to register server command. Only did unregister. Works fine now thanks sir : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.Exit(0)`. Nonzero Exit-Codes indicate an error.

> Terminates this process and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code. This is the code to call when you are using console application.

The difference to `Application.Exit()` becomes clear when looking at the documentation.

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

But be careful with `Environment.Exit()` since it kills the process immediatly. You may want to investigate why `Application.Exit()` is not able to close your application.

Comment: Still loads form1 for me when I use Environment.Exit :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want this code in the form constructor. Instead, find your entry point (usually a static `Main` method in the `Program.cs` file), and put it there.

`Application.Exit` is already a bit of a bad sign - it shows that you don't really know what you're trying to exit at that point. The reason it doesn't work in your case is that there's no application to exit yet - the usual way a winforms application is started looks something like this:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Since you're in the form constructor, `Application.Run` didn't run yet, so there's no message loop to exit (which is what `Application.Exit` does).

You'll also have direct access to command-line arguments from the entry point - it's an argument to the `Main` method. Do all your decisions there, and only if you want to actually run the GUI application, do the `Application.Run`. Otherwise, just return from `Main` and your application will end (provided you didn't spin up any foreground threads that are still alive at that point).