# How to Default a program using c#

Tags: c#

I created a media player in winforms.i want to default it using c#.when you clicked an mp3 anywhere ,windows media player open that mp3file.i want to my program open files when double clicked on a mp3 or other files.

I hope someone helps me.

Comment: File associations are set in the registry as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application

Answer (score -1):

Right click an MP3 file > Open With > Choose Default Program and then choose your application by browsing to the .exe file of your application.

Comment: I did it by mp3 did not played.just program opend as useul

Comment: From the sounds of OP's comment, I believe it's not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application. It seems likely that OP's program is not reading parameters from the command-line correctly since it does open.
[code]
static void Main(string[] args)

Comment: Oops. Exceeded the time limit for fixing my comment above. @Moh3en: you're app probably just needs to handle command line arguments.

Here's some quasi code:
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mp3File = null;
        if (args.Length > 0)
            mp3File = args[0];
        // do something with your mp3File..
    }

Alternatively you could also use
     `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`
as shown here (just keep in mind that the first value in the array is the executable itself): https://stackoverflow.com/a/18448925/7270462