# Accessing command line arguments from outside of main

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI WinForms project and in which I can happily print out the command line arguments in main using the following code

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    for each(String^ arg in args) {
        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(arg);
    }
}
```

Is there a built in function that allows me to access these arguments again during the program or do I need to save them myself?

I've seen [this question, specifically the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application) that says you can do this in C#:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

But is there a way specifically in C++/CLI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command-line arguments to a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application)

Comment: @TomBlodget I think whilst similar, it is a different language so *ever so slightly* different in the function call and return object

Comment: It's the same .NET question with the same .NET BCL answer(s). Not even Microsoft duplicates their .NET documentation for different programming languages. Having separate questions dilutes the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of my question is available in C++/CLI, you can do it like so:

```
array<System::String ^> ^args = System::Environment::GetCommandLineArgs();
```