# Is that possible to passing parameters in C# form app like console app?

Tags: c#

I know, how i can passing parameters in console app but i don't know, how i can do it in form app.

Example of passing parameters in console app:

My parameters: run `ConsoleApp.exe HelloWorld`

```
static void Main(string args)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(args);
    }
```

I already tried this but, it keep coming up with error:

```
public Test(string args)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show(args);
        }
```

My code:

```
public partial class test : Form
public test(string args)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show(args);

        }
private void test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: `args` is a string array, not a string.

Comment: [`GetCommandLineArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Environment_GetCommandLineArgs) as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application)? There seem to be quite a few results when searching with <your favorite search engine> for `command line arguments in windows forms c#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put parameters in `Main()`, just like a console app.

Comment: I know, what i did wrong. i tried and add above code to Form1.cs file instead of Program.cs
This is the reason of it keep coming up with error.
Thanks for help guys