# Opening application with file C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm making a Notepad replica in my spare time just for fun, the core of the project is all done. However, I can't open my application from a file. For example, if you had a .txt file, you double click it and it would open the app (by default its Notepad).

I already know how to set the default application, but the code does not support opening the files yet, it can only open files from the menu inside the program.

How would I go about making it so that my application can be opened by files?

Comment: checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass command-line arguments to a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application)

Answer (score 0):

in you `void Main(string[] args)` method, the `args` will contain the path to the file that was opened with your application. You can also get them anywhere in the application by calling `string[] Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`. Print the argument in a message box to see what arguments have been passed.

Here's some code you might want to use for that:

```cs
//In a form

public void MyButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, args));
}
```

Comment: Odd choice of using a `MessageBox` for an example of a notepad-like app.. but it works.

Comment: @CodeStranger not for the final version, simply to see what the application receives when it's started with a file as an argument.

Comment: I've seen applications receiving full URIs like `file://`

Comment: i used that solution and it seemed to work, however my application just doesnt open when opening it from a file. the mouse cursor shows that it loads but the application doesnt open.

Answer (score 0):

I like your question.  Once you provide support for opening type files, and you find that your application is still not working, perhaps this might be useful: you can check under registry section HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for the extension and action details. It talks about default applications, but it gets into more details.

Here's the page:

[Finding the default application for opening a particular file type on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162331/finding-the-default-application-for-opening-a-particular-file-type-on-windows)